# "through the hours" meaning

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I struggle to translate *through the hours* into my mother language.

It comes from a song by Glen Hansard. (*My Little Ruin*: [See the third paragraph](https://play.google.com/music/preview/Tjlbk5gnyfy5gy7fshx2bbvrf3y?lyrics=1&utm_source=google&utm_medium=search&utm_campaign=lyrics&pcampaignid=kp-lyrics).)

I know what it means literally, but I also feel there must be something deeper that I do not quite get.

Answer (score 1):

The actual phrasing is

> *struggle though* the hours

To *struggle through* is to endure with great effort.

In *My Little Ruin* the singers is saying that a person has gone through many difficulties in life

> [“It’s me saying to a friend or a friend saying to me, ‘Come on, pick yourself up, you’re all right’ ”](http://www.theaustralian.com.au/arts/review/once-star-glen-hansard-on-the-stage-musicals-australian-debut/news-story/a3dfeb56b8ae1f41e27521f2704bde4b)

and often in life, one must  and can only endure as opposed to thrive.